# Triggering model validation with CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model

I'm creating a form so users can change their passwords. This form is in my settings controller, but I'm saving the data to my users table.

I have the following form

```
settings/index.ctp

echo $this->Form->create('settings');
echo $this->Form->input('current_password');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->input('repass', array('type'=>'password', 'label'=>'Re-Enter Password'));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

Here's my Setting model

```
function equalToField($array, $field) {
    print_r($array); //check to see if it was even being triggered...it's not!
    return strcmp($this->data[$this->alias][key($array)], $this->data[$this->alias][$field]) == 0;
}

public function beforeSave() {

    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}


 public $validate = array(
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
            'message' => 'A password with a minimum length of 8 characters is required'
        )
    ),
    'repass' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('equalToField', 'password'),
            'message' => 'Passwords do not match'
        )
    )
);
```

And the code in my SettingsController to save it

```
$password = Security::hash($this->request->data['settings']['current_password'], NULL, true);
$this->loadmodel('User');
$options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => AuthComponent::user('id')));
$user = $this->User->find('first', $options);

if($user['User']['password'] == $password){ //current password match 
    $this->User->id = AuthComponent::user('id');
    $this->User->saveField('password',Security::hash($this->request->data['settings']['password'], NULL, true));
}
else{
    $this->Session->setFlash('Current password is incorrect'); 
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly that the validation isn't triggering? I'd prefer to keep this in my SettingsController if possible. Also, before anyone mentions it I plan on making the current password match into one of the validation criteria...just as soon as I get it working.

**Update - I decided to do some digging around**

In /lib/Model/Model.php I went to the validator function and printed the validator object, here's what I found

```
([validate] => Array ( 
        [password] => Array ( 
             [required] => Array ( 
                  [rule] => Array ( 
                       [0] => minLength 
                       [1] => 8 ) 
                       [message] => A password with a minimum length of 8 characters is required ) ) 
        [repass] => Array ( 
             [required] => Array ( 
                   [rule] => Array ( 
                        [0] => equalToField 
                        [1] => password )
                        [message] => Passwords do not match 
   ) ) ) 
 [useTable] => settings 
 [id] => 
 [data] => Array ( 
                [Setting] => Array ( 
                          [settings] => Array ( 
                                [current_password] => current_pass 
                                [password] => testpass1 
                                [repass] => testpass2 
   ) ) )
```

I'm not sure if that's what I want, but it's using settings table for this and I'm saving to the users table. I changed that value to users (by manually setting the value in that function), but it didn't change anything.

When I use the following as was suggested, it pulls the validation from the UserModel not Settings

```
$this->User->set($this->request->data);
if($this->User->Validates() == true){
```

Comment: This might also help: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

Comment: Not sure why I haven't spotted that... Now I'm confused, what are you doing there? Why are you using the `User` model to save something that belongs to the `Setting` model?

Comment: @ndm it's being saved in the users table, not the settings table. I'm doing this from the SettingsController/model

Comment: Ok, but how do your expect this to work? You are defining the validation on the `Setting` model (at least that's what I assume when you say "_Here's my Setting model_"), but you are using the `User` model, that's what doesn't make sense to me, and I'm not sure whether this is a mistake that I should elaborate in my answer, or whether you are doing some funky stuff like extending the `Setting` model or something.

Comment: @ndm How do I save it to the users table then? Is my only option to put it in the UsersController? Can I only save to the table for the model I'm validating with?

Comment: The model that validates the data doesn't necessarily need to be the one that saves the data, but I'd say it's recommended, ie you should validate and save through the `User` model. The controller is irrelevant, you can use your model in any controller. Give me a few minutes and I'll update my answer with further explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's start with a fresh, new answer. There are various problems here.

## 1. Mixing up models

You are defining the validation rules and stuff on the `Setting` model, but in your code snippet you are using the `User` model for saving the data, so if at all, it would apply the validation rules defined on the `User` model. So while it's possible to use a different model for validation than for saving, I wouldn't recommend that, I would instead use the `User` model for all these jobs.

That means, put the validation rules and methods in your `User` model (that is hopefully linked to the `users` table).

---

## 2. Lowercase/plural notation for model names

You are using lowercase/plural notation for model names, where it should be singular starting with a capital letter:

```
$this->Form->create('Setting');

$this->request->data['Setting']
```

Please note that this is just for demonstration purposes, as mentioned above you should use the `User` model, ie:

```
$this->Form->create('User');

$this->request->data['User']
```

---

## 3. Validation is applied to explicitly passed data only

[`Model::saveField()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false) only validates the data that was explicitly passed to it, ie it would only validate the `password` field, and you couldn't access any other fields from your validation methods since the data is not set on the model.

So instead you'll either have to use [`Model::save()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) with a list of allowed fields supplied (you could also utilize [`Model::set()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-set-one-two-null)):

```
$this->User->id = AuthComponent::user('id');
$this->User->save($this->request->data, true, array('password', 'repass'));
```

or you do [trigger validation manually](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html):

```
$this->User->id = AuthComponent::user('id');
$this->User->set($this->request->data);
if($this->User->validates() === true)
{
    $this->User->saveField('password', Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password'], NULL, true));
}
```

Note that in this scenario you could also use a different model for validation, ie:

```
$this->Setting->set($this->request->data);
if($this->Setting->validates() === true)
{
    $this->User->saveField('password', Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password'], NULL, true));
}
```

However, I think it's better to use the User model, if necessary change validation rules dynamically so that they fit your needs. For example by removing rules:

```
$this->User->validator()->remove('field_x')
                        ->remove('field_y')
                        ->remove('field_z');
```

Or by overriding the validation rules:

```
$this->User->validate = array
(
    ...
);
```

However, both is best to be done from within the model.

---

## 4. Triggering validation with `Model::saveField()`

Last but not least, the `Model::saveField()` method has 3 parameters, where the third one is a either a `boolean` value (defaults to `false`), defining whether or not to use validation, or an `array` that takes the options `validate`, `callbacks` and `counterCache`.

So you would have to set `true` as the third parameter in order for validation being triggered by `Model::saveField()` at all:

```
$this->User->saveField('password', Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password'], NULL, true), true);
```

---

ps. are you aware that you are currently hashing twice? First directly when passing the data to `Model::saveField()`, and then a second time in `Model::beforeSave()`.

Comment: WOW! You really went all out. Thank you so much!